# Question about SQLite3 and updating iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

Consider the following scenario.

I have an iPhone app in the app store which performs queries on a 16 column SQLite3 table. As an update, I want to add a new column to this table.

When someone installs the update, will it mess up? Will the table get replaced? How does this work. How should I handle this?

Comment: Since sqlite 3 doesn't support adding columns, you'll need to rename the old table, create a new table with all columns, including the new one, then populate the new table from the old table, and then finally drop the old table.

Comment: are you 100% certain it doesn't work? because I'm pretty sure it does...

Comment: it definitely does work...i installed a database without the column in my application. it added a column. and it definitely works because the second time it didn't add it.

Comment: oh yes sorry, I got confused by my past experience... thing is that I ran into issues due to certain limitations of adding columns, mostly with dealing with new foreign key, as well as the ordering of the columns, and since then I've just been always following the procedure I mentioned earlier - again, sorry for the noise.

Comment: so will my database get completely replaced when the app is installed? I dragged the databse into the "frameworks" folder when I made the app. i'm concerned that it will completely replace the old database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be to check at launch time if the table has the new field. You can use the following SQLite command to retrieve all fields from a table

```
PRAGMA table_info(table-name);
```

If the field you're looking is not in the result set, execute an `ALTER TABLE table-name ADD COLUMN column-name column-type` to update your table.

You can use this method to loop through the fields of a table

```
- (BOOL)getFields
{
    const char *sql = "PRAGMA table_info(myTable)";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *fieldName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
        NSLog(@"%@", fieldName);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can you provide more code for "retrieving all fields from a table"?

Comment: I want to check if there exists a column with the name "Apple"

Comment: I have updated the answer with a method to loop through the fields

Comment: @WTP SQLite version 3.1.4 and up support [adding columns](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Comment: 3.1.4 has been out for 6 years, WTP. :)

Comment: In our only app that uses sqlite directly, we use `PRAGMA user_version` to determine the "database version" that increments between releases. The code used to simply execute the `ALTER TABLE` on every launch and ignore errors.

Answer (score 1):

FYI if you never copied the database to make it editable, it will be replaced. If you copied the DB to somewhere that is writeable, then you have to handle the replacing yourself.

Comment: what do you mean? I dragged the database into my frameworks folder when I first made the app. Will it get replaced in the update?

Comment: That's exactly what David Hodge just answered. You didn't copy, therefore it'll be replaced.

Comment: Anything that is simply included in the app when you submit it gets replaced with an update. In iOS, your app bundle is readonly and is meant to contain precisely what you submitted to Apple with the latest update. So for you that means you'll have the latest DB baked in there.